# Profile Details not working in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a simple website with asp.net mvc 4 and entity framework 6 where user can login and see a mssql table data and also can view their profile. So far everything was working fine but when I implemented a method for viewing profile I get an error of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` whenever I try to login. If I comment out the Profile Viewing part, I can login & see the table data. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
mytestdbEntities testdb = new mytestdbEntities();
public ActionResult ProfileView(int id=0)
    {
        UserInfo profile = testdb.UserInfoes.Find(id);
        TableAndProfile model = new TableAndProfile();
        model.UserInfoo = new List<UserInfo>();
        model.UserInfoo.Add(profile);
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }

 public ActionResult UserLogin()
    {
        if(Session["UserBOID"] != null)
        {
            var mkimodel = new TableAndProfile { ExTables = dsedb.ExTables.ToList() };
            return View(mkimodel);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class TableAndProfile
{
    public List<UserInfo> UserInfoo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ExTable> ExTables { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model AProzLtd.Models.TableAndProfile
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                
            @if (@Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                <li>Welcome, <b>@Session["UserID"].ToString()</b></li>
            }
            @foreach(var item in Model.UserInfoo)
            {
                <li><a class="btn btn-info" href="@Html.ActionLink("ProfileView", "Home", new { id=item.UserId })" target="_blank"><b>Profile</b></a></li>
            }
</ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.ExTables) {    
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COLUMN_ONE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COLUMN_TWO)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

**MSSQL Login Table Data Snapshot**
[image: Login Table]

**Error**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Line 38:                 @foreach(var item in Model.UserInfoo)

As far I don't see any NULL values in my table, I don't see any reason getting this error. How can I fix that? Is there something wrong with my code? If so, please I need a solution badly. Your help will be appreciated. Tnx.

Comment: Are you sure its that one and not `@foreach (var item in Model.ExTables) { ` which would throw an exception because you don't appear to have initialized `ExTables`?

Comment: Why do you use `return View(profile)`, I think you should use `return View(model)`, because you have a strogly typed view for TableAndProfile

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please see my update in controller. I've added the method for viewing table data from ExTable.

Comment: @AlexVazhev, I've updated my code. I did what you said, still same error.

Comment: why are you returning a list which can only ever hold and display one element? Is your plan at some point for one user to have more than one profile? And your default for `id=0`, so what happens there? You aren't checking for a missing profile, only for a missing session value.

Comment: Does List is supposed to hold one record from table?

Comment: Also, is that HTML from the `UserLogin()` View or the `ProfileView()` View? what URL string is being used to call up that ActionResult?

Comment: You definitely don't need a `List<>` if you are only ever planning on holding one record.

Comment: you dont have anything with id = 0 in ur table

Comment: @AndrewCounts, HTML is for UserLogin(). So if I don't use List then what should my code look like?

Comment: well if that html page is for `UserLogin()` then that's your problem right there.  You don't have a `UserInfoo` property assigned in that ActionResult at all.

Comment: But I've added the model in the view. Please check my code. `TableAndProfile` model has UserInfoo property.

Comment: @Neel, Should I use `UserId` then?

Comment: yes, but when you create the ViewModel (`var mkimodel = new TableAndProfile { ExTables = dsedb.ExTables.ToList() };`) you don't create any `UserInfoo`, so of course it will be `null` on the page.

Comment: @SinOscuras, You added some code in the `UserLogin()` method, not the `ProfileView()` method. Both will cause a problem. In `ProfileView` you will throw an exception at `@foreach (var item in Model.ExTables) { ` because you have not initialized `ExTables` and for `UserLogin` you will throw an exception at`@foreach(var item in Model.UserInfoo)` because you have not initialized `UserInfoo`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You really need to study a bit more about how Models and Views work, I think, because what you have is haphazard and doesn't fully make sense.  Why would you be looping through looking for a profile on the login page before they have logged in to have a profile? and I'm not sure why you don't understand the alternatives to using a `List` of items for a single item... use the item itself.

Comment: So should I use ProfileView() codes in UserLogin() method?

Comment: why would you use the codes for one ActionResult in a different one that performs a different function?

Comment: @AndrewCounts, I used the ProfileView() as a link so that user can see their profile after clicking and ofcourse they should be logged in in UserLogin() view. UserLogin() view will only show the ExTable data. Are we clear now?

Comment: well that's how it should work, but that's not what you are showing here.

Comment: Ok then what will it should be like in your opinion? Better if you show me code example.

Comment: this isn't a code writing service.  If you can't understand the obvious flaws in the code you have after multiple people tried to explain it, then any supplied code isn't example at all, it ends up in your production software, with you not understanding what it does or how to fix it if it doesn't work exactly right.  Learn to problem solve a bit here.

Comment: @SinOscuras, Get rid of `TableAndProfile`. One method is for displaying `IEnumerable<ExTables>` so that's the model for its view. The other is displaying `UserInfoo` so that's the model for its view. You menu should be in a layout or separate partial and since your storing the userID in session, then if it exists - `@Html.ActionLink("ProfileView", "Home", new { id=@Session["UserID"] })`. Having looked at some of your previous questions, its clear your not understanding the basics, so spend some quality time working through the information on the MVC site and other tutorials.